# C++11 thread::id special value that represent no thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

This [man page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id) states that

> Instances of this class may also hold the special distinct value that does not represent any thread.

But I couldn't find nowhere what would be this special value or where it is defined (looked in < thread >). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default constructor is documented thusly:

> Default-constructs a new thread identifier. The identifier does not
>   represent a thread.

So if you want the not-a-thread identifier, just default-construct an `id`.  The default-constructed value can be compared with any thread `id` to check if the latter is not-a-thread.